# view transmission status through cli

Tags: command-line, transmission

I have installed transmission, and i have added a torrent to it, now how will i be able to view the details of the torrents.

i have tried transmission-remote on local system.

```
m@m-170:/home/m/$ transmission-remote -n transmission:transmission -st

CURRENT SESSION
  Uploaded:   None
  Downloaded: None
  Ratio:      None
  Duration:   1 hour, 31 minutes (5478 seconds)

TOTAL
  Started 1 times
  Uploaded:   None
  Downloaded: None
  Ratio:      None
  Duration:   1 hour, 31 minutes (5478 seconds)
```

and when i view my transmission gui it is currently downloading

how can i see the status, current download and upload speed
and also add and remove torrents

Edit:

i have check an my default username and password is transmission
so when i go here

```
http://localhost:9091/
```

and type username and password, i see the web interface of the transmission, but i dont see the current downloading in the gui.

is there a way in transmission command line, that i can check what is in my gui and its status of my torrents

Comment: Is `transmission-remote -n user:pass -l` not doing what you want?

Answer (score 2):

I'm using `transmission-remote-cli`. It is a Curses interface communicating with the Transmission instance (locally or on the net) using the RPC protocol. Check the [Debian package](http://packages.debian.org/sid/transmission-remote-cli).

On server:

```
sudo apt-get install transmission-cli transmission-daemon transmission-common
mkdir /home/user/torrents
sudo chown -R debian-transmission:debian-transmission torrents

sudo service transmission-daemon stop

sudo vim /etc/transmission-daemon/settings.json

"download-dir": "/home/user/torrents",
"rpc-authentication-required": true,
"rpc-enabled": true,
"rpc-whitelist-enabled": false,

sudo service transmission-daemon start
```

On client

```
yaourt -S transmission-remote-cli
transmission-remote-cli -f ~/.trclirc --create-config
vim ~/.trclirc

password = transmission
username = transmission
port = 9091
host = 75.127.14.127
```

Start transmission curses interface with

```
transmission-remote-cli -f ~/.trclirc
```

Comment: doesn't work for me when I put the files inj user's home dir

Comment: The defualt path for transmission-remote-cli is `~/.config/transmission-remote-cli/settings.cfg`.

Put it there and then you don't have to load it manually.